# Redirect all traffic from IP alias to hyperv virtual machine

Tags: routing, hyper-v, nat, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows server 2016 instance with one nic and two IP aliases. It's possible to route all traffic from one IP to a virtual machine running on hyperv? The virtual machine is running Ubuntu with nginx. So I want al .net sites be served from iis running on the host on IP A and serve Al PHP sites from the Ubuntu vm on IP B

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using the below command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=IPB connectport=80 connectaddress=IPVM
```